# The color-coding of file types in my terminal has stopped, help?

Tags: unity, command-line

I was messing around in the terminal earlier and the way file types and directories are color coded has stopped. Now when I pull up a list of all files in a directory, they are all white.  What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch a terminal and enter `ls --color`, is the output in color?

Try logging out of your desktop and back in again, test `ls` in a terminal again - what happens?

If the above hasn't helped you can alias `ls` to `ls --color` in `~/.bashrc` .. simply add a line to that file : `alias ls='ls --color'`

Comment: Well I tried the ls --color and it came out in color.  But then when I did ls again in was all in white.

Comment: @LurkDog you modified your `.bashrc` file, it seems.  So you have to add back the line that says `alias ls='ls --color'` as JasonD said.

Comment: I don't know how to find the .bashrc file in the terminal so I found one in the GUI called dot.bashrc which listed about 4 alias'. I put the new alias in but it wouldn't let me save it. Sorry I'm new at this